# Bar notation in base-10 log scale in ggplot2

Tags: r

Many years ago, engineers used a bar notation for negative base-10 logarithms (bar over the characteristic). Is there a way to use the bar notation in ggplot2? If not, how can I create custom breaks with Unicode, as in "\bar{2}.07918" or something along those lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `labels` argument to convert each label to a plotmath expression. If I understand you correctly, you are looking for the exponent-mantissa representation of numbers as used in the days of slide rules and log tables, where the negative values of the exponent were represented by bars above the numbers. This requires a little function to generate the labels:

```r
bar_notation <- function(x) {
  mantissa <- log10(x) - floor(log10(x))
  exponent <- floor(log10(x))
  e <- ifelse(exponent < 0, paste0("bar(", -exponent, ")"), paste(exponent))
  m <- ifelse(mantissa == 0, "000", substr(as.character(mantissa), 3, 6))
  parse(text = paste(e, "*.*", m))
}
```

We can pass this function directly to the `labels` argument of `scale_y_log10`. For demonstration purposes, let's use the powers of `e` as breaks on our axis:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_boxplot(fill = "lightblue") +
  scale_y_log10(labels = bar_notation, breaks = exp(seq(-4, 4))) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

---

To interpret these numbers, we simply add the values on each side of the period (with the negative values denoted by the bar). For example, we can see on our plot that the lowest value of `y` is just below the bar(2).2628. To find out what this number represents, we can do -2 + 0.2628 =  -1.7372. This means the value on the y axis is 10^-1.7372, or 0.01831471. We can confirm the lowest value of y is just below this:

```r
min(df$y)
#> [1] 0.01766628
```

**Data used**

```r
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 10), y = 10^runif(20, -2, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks! The bar notation uses the characteristic and mantissa, but I think I can figure out the rest. I just did not know how to get the bar symbol to display as ggplot breaks.